# Alternative to nested classes?

Tags: python, class, nested, pickle

I'm using nested classes to structure my data and data specific functions (can't get indentation right in the code snippet, sorry):

```
class test:
    class AA:
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = "ZZ-top"
            self.flag = False
        def reset(self):
            self.name = "AArdvark"
            self.flag = True
    class BB:
        def __init__(self):
            self.num = 11
        def checker(self):
            if self.num > 10:
                test.AA.name = "Toasty"                     
    def __init__(self):
        self.AA = self.AA()
        self.BB = self.BB()
```

For me this is the neatest, easiest way to segregate my data by class. I often have the same data coming from different sources and would like to have that represented. Eg. data.image.latitude and data.csv.latitude. I would also like to have functions that get or set data from multiple classes. Eg: checker function.

The problem is python doesn't seem to like nested classes. I'm running into trouble with pickle (Can't pickle class 'test.BB.num'. This seems to be a common pickle/nested class problem) and some functions that want info on neighbouring classes don't work. I guess I have to abandon the nested classes.

What is the python'esque correct way of structuring this data? Should I just have one monstrously big class (self.AA_timeofday ... self.ZZ_timeofday) with all the functions in it or is there something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There rarely is a need to nest classes, and other than wrapping the name of the class in another namespace and breaking pickling there is no difference in functionality.

Just put the classes at the global level of your module:

```
class AA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "ZZ-top"
        self.flag = False
    def reset(self):
        self.name = "AArdvark"
        self.flag = True

class BB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 11
    def checker(self):
        if self.num > 10:
            test.AA.name = "Toasty"   

class test:                  
    def __init__(self):
        self.AA = AA()
        self.BB = BB()
```

Comment: Yup, that's done it. Simple solution that I can't believe I've missed.

Comment: how to call the checker() function?  I keep getting AttributeError when trying to run it.

Comment: @MehrdadMehraban: without details on how you created instances or what instance you tried to call it on, or what the attribute error might be, I can't help.